# React Jsx - How to hook RxJs click event for random quote generator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, api, rxjs

This is my component, quite simply, a quote generator. Quite interesting, as the quotes refresh when the entire site refreshes. So in this case we would want to have a single onClick() event to trigger our event and to re-generate the component maybe? So far this is what i've got:

```
import React from 'react';
import { of } from 'rxjs'
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/ajax'
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators'
import IQuote from '../../contracts/IQuote';

class QuoteComponent extends React.Component {
    private subscription: any;
    public state: any;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            content: undefined, 
            originator: {
                id: undefined,
                language_code: undefined,
                content: undefined,
                url: undefined,
                originator: undefined,
                name: undefined,
                tags: undefined
            }
        }
    }

    fetchNewQuote() {
        let url = "https://quotes15.p.rapidapi.com/quotes/random/?language_code=en";
        let headers = {
            "x-rapidapi-host": "quotes15.p.rapidapi.com",
            "x-rapidapi-key": "<<API KEY>>"
        };

        const observable$ = ajax.getJSON(url, headers)
          .pipe(
            map(response => response),
            catchError(error => of(error))
          )

        this.subscription = observable$.subscribe((result) => {
            this.setState(result)
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchNewQuote();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    render () {

        function onClickHandler(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.fetchNewQuote(); {/* problem! */}
        }

        return (
                <div className="streak-view streak streak-lg streak-photo">
                    <div className="streak-pattern flex-center pattern-6 mask">
                        <ul className="white-text smooth-scroll">
                            <li>
                                <h2 onClick={onClickHandler} className="h2-responsive wow fadeIn" style={{visibility: "visible", animationName: "fadeIn", fontSize: "20px"}}>
                                    <i className="fa fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        &nbsp;{this.state.content}&nbsp;
                                    <i className="fa fa-quote-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </h2>
                            </li>
                            <li><h5 className="text-center font-italic wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.2s" style={{visibility: "visible", animationDelay: "0.2s", animationName: "fadeIn"}}>
                                &nbsp;-&nbsp;{this.state.originator.name}
                                </h5>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
        )
    }
}

export default QuoteComponent;
```

Comment: Sorry, so you're asking how to make it refresh on click? If this, then just call `this.fetchNewQuote()` within your onClickHandler.

Comment: That is exactly what I though of doing at first, but for some reason the typescript compile keeps returning this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetchNewQuote' of undefined`

Comment: You'll have to change fetchNewQuote() on the class to an arrow function to avoid that. `fetchNewQuote = () => {} `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question... you could do something like this:

```
render () {
    // make this an arrow function so "this"
    // references the class instead of the function handler itself
    const onClickHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.fetchNewQuote();
    };
...
```